# How can I randomize setTimeout time

Tags: jquery

I wrote this simple jQuery script to popup my `#popup` div but not every 2 seoncds or 3 I want time to be generated with `Math.random()` here's code but unfortunately it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function pop(){
            $('#popup').show();
            $('#content').addClass('blur');
        };
    setTimeout(pop,el);
    $('#x').click(function(){
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#content').removeClass('blur');
    });
var el = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);
})
```

Comment: Your code isn't correct. You should define the value of `el` before setting the timeout. When you set the timeout, the value of `el` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, `Math.random()` will return a number between `0` and `1`.

**JavaScript Console**

```
>> Math.random()
<- 0.8419219077751203
```

If you want a larger random number, you can use a multiplier. For Milliseconds, there are `1000` in `1` second, so if we want a random number of Milliseconds, between `0` and `1000`, we can multiply the result by `1000`.

```
>> Math.random() * 1000
<- 188.6188679027202
```

We're essentially just moving the decimal. Now if we want a random number of milliseconds between 2 seconds and 3 seconds, we can add `2000` to compensate. Now instead of being between `0` and `1000`, it's between `2000` and `3000`.

```
>> (Math.random() * 1000) + 2000
<- 2494.96714163502
```

Now you have to make a decision about the remaining decimal content. You can `Math.round()` or `Math.floor()`.

```
>> Math.round(2494.96714163502)
<- 2495
>> Math.floor(2494.96714163502)
<- 2494
```

1 ms should not make a large difference in your timer, so you can use whichever you like.

So if you need a random number of milliseconds from 2 to 3 seconds, you're done. If you need to create more random timers, then see the other posted answer. This creates a Range between `0` and `n`, where `n` is not 0 and not less than 0, and a Base (`b`):

```
>> Math.floor((Math.random() * (3000 - 2000)) + 2000)
<- 2556
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  function getRandomMillisecond(min, max){
    if(max - min <= 0){
      return 1;
    }
    return Math.floor((Math.random * (max - min)) + min);
  }

  function pop(){
    $('#popup').show();
    $('#content').addClass('blur');
  };

  setTimeout(pop, getRandomMillisecond(2000, 3000));

  $('#x').click(function(){
    $('#popup').hide();
    $('#content').removeClass('blur');
  });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The main problem in the code is that the OP does the `el = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000);` after `el` is used in `setTimeout`, that is an important part that has to be targeted in the answer, as replacing `var el = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)` with  `var el =  getRandomMillisecond(2000, 3000);` in the original code would not change anything.

Comment: @t.niese that is addressed in the order of operations in my code example. I agree that `el` got defined later than it is used. I just avoided using it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) // min and max included
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

randomIntFromInterval(3000, 5000);
```

This would be a random interval between 3 seconds and 5 seconds.

If you want it in between 2 and three seconds, you would write:

```
randomIntFromInterval(2000, 3000);
```

The values (2000, 3000) are milliseconds.

Comment: This does not explain in any way why the code of the OP does not work, nor does it provide a solution to the problem.